# How to block all access to a google cloud bucket

Tags: cloud, gcloud, bucket

I am looking to stop all read and write access to a google cloud bucket that I own.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Looked up a lot of info about ACLs but can;t seem to figure out exactly what permission to apply to the bucket

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to use Cloud Console's Storage Browser.

You'll need to know under which Project (`${PROJECT}) your bucket resides:

`https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/?project=${PROJECT}`

Select your bucket and "SHOW INFO PANEL" in the upper right corner.

You will be provided the list of permissions that applied (direct|inherited).

Please be **VERY** careful in deleting permissions that you do not inadvertently delete yourself from the list of permitted users. I recommend you retain -- at a minimum -- two distinct permitted (groups of) users.